# How to setup multiple subdomains on lampp?

Tags: linux, cakephp, subdomain, apache-config, lampp

I need to set up multiple projects on lampp. How can i create sub domains for these multiple projects.

My projects are in cakePHP.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: This is basic apache configuration. Which linux are you using?

Comment: @Pekka: It's okay here as it's dev related.

Comment: @Leo not really - stuff like this is always dev related. Not that it's a big deal either way, but still.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just add a folder for each project in document root (usually `/var/www/` in Ubuntu) I think it's `/var/www/html/` in CentOS.

Access is then `http://localhost/projectname/`, so a Cake project called blog with an articles controller, you would do something like `http://localhost/blog/articles/view/23` to view article id=23.